# How to use the SCNNode look Method in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, arkit

Im Programming a Xamarin iOS AR app.
Im trying to display an arrow in my ARSCNView that points to a specific node.

The method I use to add the arrow:

```
 private void AddDirectionArrow()
    {
       
            var arrow = SCNScene.FromFile("arrow.dae");

            if (arrow is null)
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Pfeil 3D Modell nicht gefunden");
            }

            this.ArrowNode = arrow.RootNode;
            this.ArrowNode.Position = new SCNVector3(0, 3, -8f);

            this.sceneView.PointOfView?.AddChildNode(this.ArrowNode);

            this.ArrowNode.Rotation = new SCNVector4(0, 0, 1, 0);
     }
```

This works fine.The arrow stays in front of the users device.

My class has 2 nodes as property:

```
private SCNNode ArrowNode;
private SCNNode NodeToPointTo;
```

The NodeToPointTo is set as followed:

```
this.NodeToPointTo = this.sceneView.GetNode(<SomeARAnchor>);
```

Works fine as well.

In the ARDelegate.cs method `WillRenderScene` I call this method to update the arrow:

```
  public override void OnUpdateScene(double timeInSeconds)
        {
            base.OnUpdateScene(timeInSeconds);

            if (this.NodeToPointTo is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.ArrowNode.Look(this.NodeToPointTo.WorldPosition, this.sceneView.PointOfView.WorldUp, this.ArrowNode.WorldFront);
        }
```

This is what I cant figure out.

Im calling the Look method that should point my arrow node to the node I want it to point to.

How do I call this method correctly so my arrow points to the node?

Here is the [Apple Dokumentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2867396-lookat?language=objc) since I couldn't find any for Xamarin.

And the [desired outcome](https://twitter.com/RomainDerrien/status/1060282275932372992?s=21)

Don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

-Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this case which is about [one SCNNode look at another SCNNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973953/animating-scnconstraint-lookat-for-scnnode-in-scenekit-game-to-make-the-transi), you can try to use the `SCNLookAtConstraint` which is [a constraint that orients a node to always point toward a specified other node](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint).

You can try the following code:

```
private SCNNode ArrowNode;
private SCNNode NodeToPointTo;
....
SCNLookAtConstraint sCNLookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint.Create(NodeToPointTo);
ArrowNode.Constraints = new SCNLookAtConstraint[] { sCNLookAtConstraint };
```

Comment: In what method do I have to call this?

Comment: Just add the code before you use the ArrowNode. You can try to put it in the AddDirectionArrow(). @SMxller

Comment: Or just call these codes after you get the instance of the ArrowNode and NodeToPointTo. @SMxller

Comment: So I did that and the arrow points towards the target node. But only if I hold my phone flat. If I hold the phone directly on the node, the arrow turns around. The arrow is moving around a center point rather than moving on its own axis. See first picture here: [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/rotate)

Comment: Did you mean that just seems point to the  target node on the 2D not the 3D？When you call the `lookat` method, what's the result? @SMxller

Comment: Yes the arrow just moves in 2D and not in 3D. It has to do something with [IsGimbalLockEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint/1468675-isgimballockenabled). But when I set it to false the arrow does not move at all.

Comment: I'm sorry for that I have no idea about this, but [this case used the  `IsGimbalLockEnabled` and `SCNLookAtConstraint`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67957856/scenekit-scnlookatconstraint-not-impacting-orientation) may provide you some help. @SMxller